# jQuery window resize issue while scrollbar appears

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window, scrollbar

When I display the page index.php only the 4 columns of THE div id .box appears instead of 5.  . From the other side, the 5 columns of THE div id .box appears when I MINIMIZE and MAXIMALIZE the window . I spent around 4 hours and I noticed that all is good when I instead of put overflow:auto; to #panel I put overflow:scroll;. And then all is nice. On page load I get all 5 columns , and on minimize and maximize window i got 5 columns too. But I do not want to have this bar from overflow:scroll at the bottom of a #kontener. Is there another way to do it? I vote up. Thanks!
/edit
I forgot to say that all is good if there are only some of boxes on the page untill there are not as many of them untill scrollbar appears.

Not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/509/

I have the following code:
style.css

```
#panel{position:absolute;top:72px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:50px;overflow:auto;}/*overflow:scroll;*/
    #kontener{overflow:hidden;}
    .box {display:block;float:left;}
    .box_in {margin:5px;padding:5px;height:260px;border:1px solid grey;}
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onResize() {
        var cw = $('#kontener').width();
        $(".box").width(cw / 5);
    }

    $(window).load('resize', onResize);
    $(window).bind('resize', onResize);

</script>

<div id="panel">    
    <div id="kontener">
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="box_in">Box</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question and I can't see the problem in your jsfiddle, it seems to work for me.

Can I ask what you are trying to achieve here, just that 5 boxes show per row? Do the boxes have a fixed height? Is a scrollbar wanted or not wanted and why is #panel positioned absolutely? Is there a reason you can't use pure CSS with `width: 20%` to make the boxes always 1/5th of the width instead of needing to use jQuery?

Comment: I have just realised you said you don't want a scrollbar, I just don't understand what you do actually want the final appearance to be. Thanks!

Comment: An example of how you can make 5 boxes fit with just CSS, without knowing what your other requirements are: http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/511/

Comment: +Sarah, nice, but in your example the table should fit to the right too like in my example. But to do this you need to resize window. Did you resize window? I did all. I forgot to put in my code " $(document).load('resize', onResize);
 $(document).bind('resize', onResize);" :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'fit to the right'?

Comment: Your example is floated to the left side. It should be centered to the left and right side, and always fit to the width of a user monitor.

Comment: This example to me looks exactly the same as your jsfiddle, it just doesn't require jQuery. I can't see any difference between the two: http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/512/

Comment: If you want to center the text you can just use text-align:center in the CSS on .box_in eg. http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/513/ Sorry, I don't think I understand what you want as the boxes fit to the left and right side equally.

Comment: I really need auto overflow, which is not working with width: 100%.

Comment: ok, I'm glad you fixed what you wanted!

Comment: I think you can still achieve the same result as in the page you linked to with just CSS and no need for jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/515/ Just my opinion though!

Comment: Nice! Say something, I will just vote up your answer :)

Comment: Can You still tell me why it is better to use css than jquery here?

Comment: In my opinion it's because CSS is something built in to all browsers so if you can use just that instead of having to include jQuery which needs something extra in order to work and that the page has to load then it's better. jQuery functions added to events like 'window.resize' also run literally every time your browser moves even one pixel so the function runs an unnecessary number of times - see http://jsfiddle.net/3Stvu/1/ for an example - with CSS you don't have this happening over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the same effect without the need for jQuery, just CSS by using `width: 20%` on `.box` (see question comments)

http://jsfiddle.net/MtUWn/516/